# Android 2.2 How to know when somebody is typing?

Tags: android

I am developing an IM application on android 2.2 and when somebody writes to me I want to see that he is typing to me, exactly like on yahoo messenger. How could I do this on Android 2.2? If you can give me an example I would be grateful. Thank you and I'm waiting your answers.

Answer (score 3):

You can try adding a textwatcher to know if any typing activity is happening. something like this.

```
myEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
       //do something
  }

  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){
       //do something
  }

  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { 
       //do something
  }
});
```

Comment: Ok, I will try this. I will let you know if it worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This will let u know when typing is going and when it is not. But for the user on the other end of the IM to know this - Its the difficukt part. Thanks to @Cristian - I never thought of this.

Answer (score 3):

I guess that your question is deeper than varun's answer. But, it's a good start. The important thing is: how can you be notified in real time when a remote user is typing, right?

In that case, you will have to implement a push system. That way, if user A is typing something, 
user B will be notified (instead of polling a server in order to know whether or not the other is typing). You don't provide information about what technology you are using; if you are using TCP or HTTP, I highly recommend you take a look at MQTT. It will allow you to easy implement pushing on Android, and that's the way that some IM apps work.

Comment: Yes you are write. My question refers at what you just said. The technology I am using is HTTP. I will listen your advice and I will take a look at MQTT. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: +1. same opinion here. I think my answer will got give him the perfect solution, but i shud help him get to it. Since client is the place where user-activity will happen. i guess he needs to check this on the client so that he can post the details on the server. But for the user on the otherside to know this--> here comse the difficulty.

Comment: By the way, you can use MQTT for the whole IM logic. I mean... is your IM app currently sending messages in real time? If no, you can use MQTT to push new messages instead of pulling them from somewhere else.